# Loading a view in bootstrap modal in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I want to load a view in a modal when popped up.
The codes are below.

**MY CONTROLLER**

```
public function view_update_box(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $player = player::findOrFail($request->id);
            return view('admin-dashboard.includes.modals.playerForm.php', ['player', $player]);
    }
}
```

**MY VIEW (The one i want to load)**
View location: admin/includes/modals/playerForm.blade.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<fieldset>
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Player Name:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Player Name" value="{{$player->player_name}}" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email" value="{{$player->player_email}}" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <!-- Text input-->
```

**PLAYER VIEW**: This is where the Modal is triggered and also displayed

```
<div class="modal fade" id="updateModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                                                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                                            <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
                                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                                                                <h3><i class="fa fa-user m-r-5"></i> Update Player Profile</h3>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="modal-body">
                                                                <div class="row">
                                                                    <div class="col-md-12" id="update_box">
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
```

**AJAX CODE**: This is the Ajax code that triggers the modal and also suppose to render the response in the modal above

```
$('body').delegate('#updatePlayer', 'click', function(){
                                                        let id = $(this).data('id');
                                                        var token = $(this).data("token");
                                                        $.ajax({
                                                            url:'/admin/players/update',
                                                            type:'get',
                                                            data:{'id':id, '_token': token},
                                                            success: function(data) {
                                                                console.log(data)
                                                                $('#update_box').html(data);
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    });
```

**WHAT I WANT**

I want the the program to load the *admin/includes/modals/playerForm.blade.php* with the player data from database.

Please any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two mistakes in the code samples you have provided
First one is that you are saying your view location is

```
admin/includes/modals/playerForm.blade.php
```

But while you are calling the view you are using

```
'admin-dashboard.includes.modals.playerForm.php'
```

According to the directory structure you have provided this should be like

```
'admin.includes.modals.playerForm'
```

And the second one is that you need to send rendered view in response for which you can use laravels render() method on view() method.

In aggregate following lines of your code

```
$player = player::findOrFail($request->id);
        return view('admin-dashboard.includes.modals.playerForm.php', ['player', $player]);
```

should look like

```
$player = player::findOrFail($request->id);
return view('admin.includes.modals.playerForm', compact('player'))->render();
```

Everything else looks good.

Please let me know if you still face any problem.

Comment: OK...  I will look at it again and give you feedback.

Comment: Thanks very much.. our second option works for me.. i.e the RENDER option